# Python writing a .csv file with rows and columns transpose

Tags: python, python-2.7

What I have is a long list of codes that involves reading different files and in the end putting everything into different .csv

This is all my codes

```
import csv
import os.path
#open files + readlines
with open("C:/Users/Ivan Wong/Desktop/Placement/Lists of targets/Mouse/UCSC to Ensembl.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
    #find files with the name in 1st row
    for row in reader:
        graph_filename = os.path.join("C:/Python27/Scripts/My scripts/Selenoprotein/NMD targets",row[0]+"_nt_counts.txt.png")
        if os.path.exists(graph_filename):
            y = row[0]+'_nt_counts.txt'  
            r = open('C:/Users/Ivan Wong/Desktop/Placement/fp_mesc_nochx/'+y, 'r')
            k = r.readlines()
            r.close
            del k[:1]
            k = map(lambda s: s.strip(), k)
            interger = map(int, k)   
            import itertools
            #adding the numbers for every 3 rows
            def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
                "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
                args = [iter(iterable)] * n
                return itertools.izip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
            result = map(sum, grouper(3, interger, 0))       
            e = row[1]
            cDNA = open('C:/Users/Ivan Wong/Desktop/Placement/Downloaded seq/Mouse/cDNA.txt', 'r')
            seq = cDNA.readlines()
            # get all lines that have a gene name
            lineNum = 0;
            lineGenes = []
            for line in seq:
                lineNum = lineNum +1
                if '>' in line:
                    lineGenes.append(str(lineNum))
                if '>'+e in line:
                    lineBegin = lineNum

            cDNA.close

            # which gene is this
            index1 = lineGenes.index(str(lineBegin))
            lineEnd = lineGenes[index1+1]           
# linebegin and lineEnd now give you, where to look for your sequence, all that 
# you have to do is to read the lines between lineBegin and lineEnd in the file
# and make it into a single string.            
            lineEnd = lineGenes[index1+1]
            Lastline = int(lineEnd) -1

# in your code you have already made a list with all the lines (q), first delete
# \n and other symbols, then combine all lines into a big string of nucleotides (like this)     
            qq = seq[lineBegin:Lastline]
            qq = map(lambda s: s.strip(), qq)
            string  = ''
            for i in range(len(qq)):
                string = string + qq[i]
# now you want to get a list of triplets, again you can use the for loop:
# first get the length of the string
            lenString = len(string);
# this is your list codons
            listCodon = []
            for i in range(0,lenString/3): 
                listCodon.append(string[0+i*3:3+i*3])
            with open(e+'.csv','wb') as outfile:
                outfile.writelines(str(result)+'\n'+str(listCodon))
```

My problem here is the file produced looks like this:

```
 0      0      0        
'GCA'  'CTT'   'GGT'
```

I want to make it like this:

```
0  GCA    
0  CTT    
0  GGT
```

What can I do in my code to achieve this?

print result:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 3, 0, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 6, 34, 35, 32, 1, 1, 0, 4, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

print listCodon:

```
['gtt', 'gaa', 'aca', 'gag', 'aca', 'tgt', 'tct', 'gga', 'gat', 'gag', 'ctg', 'tgg', 'gca', 'gaa', 'gga', 'cag', 'gcc', 'taa', 'gca', 'cag', 'gca', 'gca', 'gag', 'ctt', 'tga', 'tct', 'ctt', 'ggt', 'gat', 'cgg', 'tgg', 'ggg', 'atc', 'cgg', 'tgg', 'cct', 'agc', 'ttg', 'tgc', 'caa', 'gga', 'agc', 'tgc', 'tca', 'gct', 'ggg', 'aaa', 'gaa', 'ggt', 'ggc', 'tgt', 'ggc', 'tga', 'cta', 'tgt', 'gga', 'acc', 'ttc', 'tcc', 'ccg', 'agg', 'cac', 'caa', 'gtg', 'ggg', 'cct', 'tgg', 'tgg', 'cac', 'ctg', 'tgt', 'caa', 'cgt', 'ggg', 'ttg', 'cat', 'acc', 'caa', 'gaa', 'gct', 'gat', 'gca', 'tca', 'ggc', 'tgc', 'act', 'gct', 'ggg', 'ggg', 'cat', 'gat', 'cag', 'aga', 'tgc', 'tca', 'cca', 'cta', 'tgg', 'ctg', 'gga', 'ggt', 'ggc', 'cca', 'gcc', 'tgt', 'cca', 'aca', 'caa', 'ctg', 'gtg', 'aga', 'gag', 'aag', 'ccc', 'ttg', 'ccc', 'tct', 'gca', 'ggt', 'ccc', 'att', 'gaa', 'agg', 'aga', 'ggt', 'ttg', 'ctc', 'tct', 'gcc', 'act', 'cat', 'ctg', 'taa', 'ccg', 'tga', 'gct', 'ttt', 'cca', 'ccc', 'ggc', 'ctc', 'ctc', 'ttt', 'gat', 'ccc', 'aga', 'ata', 'atg', 'act', 'ctg', 'aga', 'ctt', 'ctt', 'atg', 'tat', 'gaa', 'taa', 'atg', 'cct', 'ggg', 'cca', 'aaa', 'acc']
```

[image: This is what Marek's code helped me to achieve]
[image: This is what I hope for]

picture on the left is what Marek's code helped me to achieve, I want to make an improvement so it arrange like the picture on the right

Comment: What exactly is contained in `result` and `listCodon`? I'm asking because right now your code snippet implies that both are simple strings already, and the `str()` call is useless. Otherwise there would be no way to achieve that output, unless they are custom classes that overload `__str__()`, and if that was the case, we'd definitely need to see these definitions.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker result and listCodon are in the codes that I didn't put up. They are data that has been processed with python and basically result is the numbers (example I put up will be 0) and listCodon will be the 3 letters (GCA, CTT etc.)

Comment: So you've also left out a loop in your sample?  You need to post more code - we can't guess what your program is doing. Please post as much as needed for us to reproduce the result (and preferably not more than that). Then we can look at fixing it.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Right, I have done that. Do you need those raw data as well?

Comment: One tip: You're using `close` wrong, the method needs to be *called*: `cDNA.close()` is necessary (but unrelated to your problem).

Comment: @TimPietzcker Oh thanks, I am still new to python so I have a lot more to learn :/

Comment: There are *very* many things wrong with that program. You should be reading and working through a basic Python tutorial before tackling something this complicated. You're making many things extremely complicated (for example, you could simply do `string = ''.join(s.strip() for s in seq[lineBegin:Lastline]`), you're doing `import`s and `def`s in the wrong places etc...

Comment: @TimPietzcker those are the things that people taught me :/ This program is not my sole effort, I asked many questions and sort of put up bits and pieces together to make it work :'(

Comment: Another reason to read a good Python book, so you can see how much more easier you can do these things in Python. Anyway, let's not dwell on that. Can you insert a `print(result)` and `print(listCodon)` before your last line and post *exactly*  what the output of these `print`s is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `zip()` to zip together two iterators. So if you have

```
result = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
listCodons = ['gtt', 'gaa', 'aca', 'gag', 'aca']
```

then you can do

```
>>> list(zip(result, listCodons))
[(0, 'gtt'), (0, 'gaa'), (0, 'aca'), (0, 'gag'), (0, 'aca')]
```

or, for your example:

```
with open(e+'.csv','w') as outfile:
    out = csv.writer(outfile)
    out.writerows(zip(result, listCodons))
```

Comment: zip(result, listCodons) actually returns list so there's no need to wrapping it into "list" constructor.

Comment: @MarekWawrzyczek: Not on Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
proper_result = '\n'.join([ '%s %s' % (nr, codon)  for nr, codon  in zip(result, listCodon) ] )
```

**Edit (codons split into separate columns):**

```
proper_result = '\n'.join(' '.join([str(nr),] + list(codon))  for nr, codon  in zip(nrs, cdns))
```

**Edit (comma separated values):**

```
proper_result = '\n'.join('%s, %s' % (nr, codon) for nr, codon in zip(result, listCodon))
```

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax...why?

Comment: Thanks! It now its all in a column now. Although instead of 2 columns they are squeezed into 1 column. I think this is good but do you think you can separate them?

Comment: In one column? What is squeezed into 1 columny - codons?

Comment: As you know, the outfile is .csv, and when I open it, it is like an excel file with columns A, B, C etc. and row 1, 2, 3 etc.
After using your codes, the outfiles do go from top to down but the only problem is both result(the number) and listCodon(the letters) are squeezed into column A instead of what I hope for (column A for result and column B for listCodon)

Comment: Please provide sample output file which you would like to generate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14791/discussion-between-marek-wawrzyczek-and-ivanhoifung)